# Laravel Validate Array of Files Total Allowable Upload Size

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload, filesize

My View has an array of file inputs like

```
<input type="file" name="videos[]" />
<input type="file" name="videos[]" />
...
...
```

and I want to validate for the total allowable upload size (Eg: Total Allowable Upload limit is 3Mb). I've written the validation like

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
     'videos.*' => 'present|file|mimetypes:video/mp4,video/ogg|max:3000',
]);
```

but this validates for 3Mb per video.

I've tried

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'videos' => 'file|max:3000',
    'videos.*' => 'present|file|mimetypes:video/mp4,video/ogg|max:3000',
]);

/*------------------------------------------------*/

$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'videos' => 'array|max:3000',
    'videos.*' => 'present|file|mimetypes:video/mp4,video/ogg|max:3000',
]);
```

but the validation is not working for total upload size greater than 3Mb. Do I have to write a Custom Validation Rule to validate the total uploaded file size limit. Or is there any predefined validation rule? Any help appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the best way to validate the total size is by adding a custom validation rule, here is how to do that:

**In your controller:**

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'videos' => 'array|max_uploaded_file_size:3000',
    'videos.*' => 'present|file|mimetypes:video/mp4,video/ogg',
]);
```

**Register custom validation in AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() {

    Validator::extend('max_uploaded_file_size', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        
        $total_size = array_reduce($value, function ( $sum, $item ) { 
            // each item is UploadedFile Object
            $sum += filesize($item->path()); 
            return $sum;
        });

        // $parameters[0] in kilobytes
        return $total_size < $parameters[0] * 1024; 

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I've been searching for something like this earlier but never found this method. Wondering why the h*ck it isn't mentioned in the official validation documentation???

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution but, I would foreach the videos and use the php filesize function (returns integer size in bytes)

3mb = 3,145,728,000 bytes

```
foreach($request['videos'] as $video){
$size = filesize($video);
if($size > 3145728000)
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

and inside your view call this

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```