# How to validate array of files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-9

I'm working on a project where every user is able to add multiple product images. I'm using a single form to submit the product which does 2 things in ProductController@store which are creating new product + creating images belongs to this product in Images table.

**The important part** is that I want to allow users to upload total of 10mb of images per product. So mainly I want to validate total files size of the array of images the user trying to update.

I found this solution: [Laravel Validate Array of Files Total Allowable Upload Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054391/laravel-validate-array-of-files-total-allowable-upload-size/47056662#47056662)

This solution is almost 5 years old so I was wondering if there is an easier way, or a more straight forward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mixed the stackoverflow solution with Laravel's custom validation rule which solved my problem with a modern solution.

https://dev.to/moose_said/create-custom-laravel-validation-rule-for-total-uploaded-files-size-1odb